# update nao funciona pdo php

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

Pessoal estou fazendo um painel no qual o usuario envia uma imagem, mas essa imagem nao esta sendo feita

```
require_once("../classes/seguranca.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$foto = $_FILES['imagem'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$resultado = "";

$nomeMD5 = md5($nome);
//pega arquivo e mantem a extenção
if($foto['tmp_name'] != ""){

$nm_foto    = time().$nomeMD5;
$ext        = '.png';
$nmarquivo  = $nm_foto.$ext;

if(file_exists($nmarquivo)){

        unlink($nmarquivo);

        if(move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $nmarquivo)){

            $img_up = $nmarquivo;
            $nome_up = $nome;

            //inserir dados no banco
            $atualizar = "UPDATE usuarios SET foto = :img_up , nome = :nome_up , acesso = :acesso WHERE id_usuario = :id ";
            $up_perfil = $_SG['link']->prepare($atualizar);
            $up_perfil->bindValue(':img_up' , strval($img_up));
            $up_perfil->bindValue(':nome_up' , strval($nome_up));
            $up_perfil->bindValue(':id' , intval($id));
            $up_perfil->bindValue(':acesso' , 1);
            $up_perfil->execute();
            $cont = $up_perfil->rowCount();

            var_dump($up_perfil->errorInfo());

            if($cont >= 1){

                if($_SESSION['Acesso'] == 0){
                    echo "foi1";    
                var_dump($cont);
                }else{
                    echo "eita1";
                var_dump($cont);
                }
            }else{
                echo"lascou tudo </br>";
                var_dump($atualizar);
            }
        }else{
            echo "puta que o pariu";
                var_dump($nm_arquivo);
        }

}else{

    if(move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $nmarquivo)){

        $img_up = $nmarquivo;
        $nome_up = $nome;

        //inserir dados no banco
        $atualizar = "UPDATE usuarios SET foto = :img_up , nome = :nome_up , acesso = :acesso WHERE id_usuario = :id ";
        $up_perfil = $_SG['link']->prepare($atualizar);
        $up_perfil->bindValue(':img_up' , strval($img_up));
        $up_perfil->bindValue(':nome_up' , strval($nome_up));
        $up_perfil->bindValue(':id' , intval($id));
        $up_perfil->bindValue(':acesso' , 1);
        $up_perfil->execute();
        $cont = $up_perfil->rowCount();


        if($cont > 0){

                if($_SESSION['Acesso'] == 0){
                    echo "foi1";    
                var_dump($cont);
                }else{
                    echo "eita1";
                var_dump($cont);
                }
            }else{
                echo"lascou tudo </br>";
                var_dump($up_perfil->errorInfo());
            }
    }else{
        echo "mas que merda eh essa";
                var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dá algum erro? Qual é o código HTML? Qual o resultado de `var_dump($_FILES)`? O banco de dados é atualizado? Quais mensagens aparecem na tela?

Comment: Verifique se a pasta onde você tá tentando upar as imagens está com permissão.

Comment: Não aprece nehum erro todos os var_dump do files esta correto com item e tudo mais o erro esta sendo no update para o banco de dados

Comment: a pasta esta com permissao sim